# Ligature containing hyphen breaks previous ligature (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: luatex, ligatures

I made a font for functional harmonic analysis in music which contains ligatures and other OpenType “magic”. TobiW at [this thread](https://www.typografie.info/3/topic/37571-musikalische-funktionssymbole-als-font/) on a german-speaking typography forum showed me how to use the font which contains ligatures like `-5` and `_5` and `-~` in LuaLaTeX (by setting the `\catcode`s for `~` and `_`).

Now almost everything works but not several consectuive ligatures containing a - (hyphen) — only the last of them is rendered by LuaLaTeX. For example, `-4-4-4` should give ⁴⁴⁴ but instead it gives -4-4⁴. In contrast, `_4_4_4` gives ₄₄₄ as expected.

It’s almost certainly a ((Lua)La)TeX problem, Pango/Harfbuzz render the example correctly. TobiW suggested to turn off the TeX ligatures (like `--` for –) and redefining `\hyphenchar` but neither helped. Any idea why the hyphen still is so special?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\func}[1]{{%
\fontspec{Harmony}[RawFeature=-tlig]% turn off TeX ligatures
\hyphenchar\font=-1\relax% don’t use - for hyphenation
\catcode45=12\relax% 45=hyphen
\catcode95=12\relax% 95=underscore
\scantokens{#1\empty}% \scantokens makes catcode definitions apply to #1
}}


\begin{document}
\func{-4-4}
\func{_4_4}
\func{-- –}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS, almost forgot: I have to use LuaLaTeX for another reason, so using XeLaTeX instead (if this would help) is not an option for me.

Comment: `\hyphenchar` does nothing in LuaTeX.

Comment: @egreg according to the docu, \hyphenchar=-1 does suppress hyphenation (that's its only use).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see no difference: with `\hyphenchar\font=-1` there is still a feasible line break point after `-`. It may depend on the LuaTeX version I use (1.07).

Comment: I don't have the font and so can't test but you could try ``\prehyphenchar`\^^ad``

Comment: Thanks for your answers! `\prehyphenchar` doesn’t work for me either. I made a minimal font (only containing three characters hyphen, a, A, and a single ligature substitution -a → A) for demonstration but I don’t know how to attach it to this question …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LuaTeX you have to use `\exhyphenchar` instead of `\hyphenchar`. Also the value is queried when the paragraph is finished and after a `\hbox/\vbox` group already ended, so you could use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\harmonyfont{Harmony}

\newcommand{\func}[1]{{%
  \leavevmode
  \exhyphenchar=-1
  \hbox{%
    \harmonyfont
    \catcode`\_=12
    \scantokens{#1}% \scantokens makes catcode definitions apply to #1
  }%
}}

\begin{document}
\func{-4-4}
\func{_4_4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend not using `\fontspec`, but rather `\newfontface` in the preamble.